# sql ignore set of records if any records meet a condition

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am trying to ignore a set of records if any records meet a condition. In my case I want to ignore set of records that contain a null value. This is what I am trying to do.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 where column2 = 39 and (get rid of all set of column4 with null);
```

I thought this would work after reading other ideas.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE column2 = 39 and column4 NOT IN (
    SELECT end_date
    FROM table1
    WHERE column2 = 39 and column4 is not NULL
);
```

Here is an example of my data I am getting right now.

```
|    74  |   39 | 1980-11-05 | 1995-03-11 |
|    80  |   39 | 1982-03-23 | 1984-07-12 |
|    10  |   39 | 1988-07-17 | 2005-06-11 |
|    10  |   39 | 2016-11-09 | NULL       |
```

Here is an example of what I want my data to look like after I finish. I want the last two to go away because the primary key in column1 had a null value in column4.

```
|    74  |   39 | 1980-11-05 | 1995-03-11 |
|    80  |   39 | 1982-03-23 | 1984-07-12 |
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea with the `not in` operator, you just need to use the right columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1
WHERE  column2 = 39 AND 
       id NOT IN (SELECT id
                  FROM   table1
                  WHERE  column2 = 39 AND column4 IS NULL)
```

Comment: Which column is `id` supposed to be? I am getting this error message. `Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'`

Comment: @noobprogrammer1987 The primary key column (the left most one in the dataset your shared)